# Switch with scanf input

Tags: c, switch-statement, scanf

I am tasked with writing a simple code using a while loop to test values and return the appropriate response to the values, in this case letter grades using a switch statement.

My problem is testing for a value not inclusive of an integer. I believe I can solve the problem with a IF test prior to the switch statement. I am looking for help on phrasing this statement.

I know that I am missing what I think is an assignment IF commend after the loop. I would also be open to the suggestion of how to check for an error and write and exception code to that error.

Also if someone could be so kind, would you explain to me how the `scanf` works in terms of assigning a value from the input. I believe my problem lies in how `scanf` assigns values. I don't think my code is parsing a true value through the `switch` versus a temp value.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {    
    int grades;

    printf("Enter a value for grading in numeric form\n");

    while ((scanf("%i", &grades)) != EOF) {
        switch (grades) {
          case 10:
          case 9:
            printf("A grade of %i is an A\n", grades);
            break;
          case 8:
            printf("A grade of %i is an B\n", grades);
            break;
          case 7:
            printf("A grade of %i is an C\n", grades);
            break;
          case 6:
            printf("A grade of %i is an D\n", grades);
            break;
          case 5:
          case 4:
          case 3:
          case 2:
          case 1:
          case 0:
            printf("A grade of %i is an F\n", grades);
            break;                                                                                                  
          default:
            printf("This is not a valid entry\n");      
         }
     }
     return 0;
 }
```

I get an infinite loop error if trying to pass a character such as an A.

Comment: Also check if `scanf` actually did write `grades`.

Comment: Olaf I believe that's what I am missing how do i do that?

Comment: How about reading the `scanf` man-page?

Comment: @Olaf I Found "Each function reads characters, interprets them according to a format, and stores the results in its arguments." Which i would read as its storing the value to the (int grades) however, I don't think my code it working that way. http://www.psych.upenn.edu/~saul/parasite/man/man3/scanf.3.html

Comment: @You missed parts. Read all and understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should test that `scanf` returns `1` instead of only checking for end of file.  If you type non numeric input, `scanf` fails and returns `0` but leaves the offending input in `stdin`, the loop body executes with a potentially invalid value for `grades` and the next iteration fails again... indefinitely.

Change the code to:

```
while (scanf("%i", &grades) == 1) {
    ...
}
```

If you want your loop to be restarted in case of invalid input, change the code to this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    char buf[80];   
    int grades;

    for (;;) {
        printf("Enter a value for grading in numeric form\n");
        if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL)
            break;

        if (sscanf(buf, "%i", &grades) != 1) {
            printf("not a number: %s", buf);
            continue;
        }
        switch (grades) {
          case 10:
          case 9:
            printf("A grade of %i is an A\n", grades);
            break;
          case 8:
            printf("A grade of %i is an B\n", grades);
            break;
          case 7:
            printf("A grade of %i is an C\n", grades);
            break;
          case 6:
            printf("A grade of %i is an D\n", grades);
            break;
          case 5:
          case 4:
          case 3:
          case 2:
          case 1:
          case 0:
            printf("A grade of %i is an F\n", grades);
            break;                                                                                                  
          default:
            printf("This is not a valid grade: %d\n", grades);
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the int 1 is a value that I will be testing. It's a case in the switch. I need a test for non numeric characters so that I can test multiple items at once.

Comment: @AndrewBodin: `scanf` returns the number of successful conversions.  What exactly do you want to do if the user types a non numeric grade?

Comment: I am trying to get the switch statement to return the default. At the present moment it runs a continuous loop. I am open to suggestions on how to proceed with this. I can not test for ANSI specific characters out of range as this would work but is system dependent.

Comment: @AndrewBodin: you can read one line at a time and check for numeric input.  See my updated answer.

Comment: This works, I hate to ask can you help me understand why it works?

Comment: @AndrewBodin: you read a line of input into `buf`, then you try and parse `buf` ad an integer with `sscanf`.  If it fails, complain that the line does not contain a number, if it succeeds, handle the number.  The main difference with the previous code is it only handles one number per line where the previous code could handle multiple numbers on the same line.

Comment: Some well hidden `goto`s with `break`, `continue`,`break`,`break`, ... Yet really a good coding block.

Answer (score 1):

This works for as an optional solution, It seems to do the same as the above code.

```
int main(void) { 
int grades;
int temp;

while((temp = scanf("%i", &grades)) != EOF)
{
    if(temp == 0)
    {
        printf("Invalid charactur\ne");
        while(getchar() != '\n')
            ;
    }
    else 
        switch (grades) {
```